# Linker errors in compiling a simple pthread code under MingW

Tags: pthreads, mingw

I am trying to compile a single c++ source file test.cpp, which has a very simple code which demonstrates pthread_create(); pthread_cond_signal/pthread_cond_wait() functionality.

I have installed Mingw / Ansys on Windows XP where I am working. In the MingW prompt I do:

```
g++ -IC:/MinGW/include/ -lpthread test.cpp 
//-IC:/MinGW/include to get pthread.h
//-LC:/MinGW/bin to get pthreadGC2.dll
```

The cpp includes pthread.h as:

```
#include <pthread.h>
```

But this gave me multiple linker undefined reference errors to all pthread library functions.

What am I doing wrong here. Is it possible to build a pthread code on MingW environment on windows or not?

How to resolve this errors?

```
C:\DOCUME~1\ADESHP~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccUQhu7D.o:pthread_cond.c:(.text+0x23): undefined reference to `_imp__pthread_mutex_lock'
C:\DOCUME~1\ADESHP~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccUQhu7D.o:pthread_cond.c:(.text+0x67): undefined reference to `_imp__pthread_cond_signal'
C:\DOCUME~1\ADESHP~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccUQhu7D.o:pthread_cond.c:(.text+0x75): undefined reference to `_imp__pthread_mutex_unlock'
C:\DOCUME~1\ADESHP~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccUQhu7D.o:pthread_cond.c:(.text+0x98): undefined reference to `_imp__pthread_exit'
C:\DOCUME~1\ADESHP~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccUQhu7D.o:pthread_cond.c:(.text+0xbc): undefined reference to `_imp__pthread_mutex_lock'
C:\DOCUME~1\ADESHP~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccUQhu7D.o:pthread_cond.c:(.text+0xe8): undefined reference to `_imp__pthread_cond_wait'
C:\DOCUME~1\ADESHP~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccUQhu7D.o:pthread_cond.c:(.text+0x10f): undefined reference to `_imp__pthread_mutex_unlock'
C:\DOCUME~1\ADESHP~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccUQhu7D.o:pthread_cond.c:(.text+0x135): undefined reference to `_imp__pthread_exit'
C:\DOCUME~1\ADESHP~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccUQhu7D.o:pthread_cond.c:(.text+0x153): undefined reference to `_imp__pthread_attr_init'
C:\DOCUME~1\ADESHP~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccUQhu7D.o:pthread_cond.c:(.text+0x169): undefined reference to `_imp__pthread_mutex_init'
C:\DOCUME~1\ADESHP~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccUQhu7D.o:pthread_cond.c:(.text+0x17f): undefined reference to `_imp__pthread_attr_setdetachstate'
C:\DOCUME~1\ADESHP~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccUQhu7D.o:pthread_cond.c:(.text+0x195): undefined reference to `_imp__pthread_cond_init'
C:\DOCUME~1\ADESHP~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccUQhu7D.o:pthread_cond.c:(.text+0x1bc): undefined reference to `_imp__pthread_create'
C:\DOCUME~1\ADESHP~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccUQhu7D.o:pthread_cond.c:(.text+0x1e3): undefined reference to `_imp__pthread_create'
C:\DOCUME~1\ADESHP~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccUQhu7D.o:pthread_cond.c:(.text+0x201): undefined reference to `_imp__pthread_join'
C:\DOCUME~1\ADESHP~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccUQhu7D.o:pthread_cond.c:(.text+0x21f): undefined reference to `_imp__pthread_join'
C:\DOCUME~1\ADESHP~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccUQhu7D.o:pthread_cond.c:(.text+0x239): undefined reference to `_imp__pthread_mutex_destroy'
C:\DOCUME~1\ADESHP~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccUQhu7D.o:pthread_cond.c:(.text+0x247): undefined reference to `_imp__pthread_cond_destroy'
C:\DOCUME~1\ADESHP~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccUQhu7D.o:pthread_cond.c:(.text+0x255): undefined reference to `_imp__pthread_attr_destroy'
C:\DOCUME~1\ADESHP~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccUQhu7D.o:pthread_cond.c:(.text+0x263): undefined reference to `_imp__pthread_exit'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: The MinGW distributions I've used do not come with a pthread library.  Do you actually have one (one is available from http://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/)?

Comment: @Michael Burr: I did not install pthread on MingW explicitly. But since I saw pthreadGC2.dll in trhe MingW binary folder, i presumed it supported pthread calls. No?

Comment: Thanks for the link to pthread-Win32. Just a query then what is then the pthread.h header and pthreadgc2.dll in MinGW are?

Comment: @Michael Burr - Downloaded the prebuild pthread-win32 libraries *.dll, *.lib. Copied these libraries to MingW bin, lib folders. Still same linker errors. tried to compile using - g++ -I/c/MinGW/include -L/c/MinGW/bin/ -L/c/MinGW/lib/ -lpthread test.cpp  Any further pointers?

Comment: Apparently some MinGW distributions do have `pthread-w32` included (TDM MinGW, for example). I was unaware of that until just now...  If your distribution has the pthread library, I'd suggest using it instead of the one from `sourceware.org` as there are quite possibly some compatibility patches applied (there are in the TDM version).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to specify the library on the gcc/g++ command line after the files that depend on the library.  So try:

```
g++ -IC:/MinGW/include/ test.cpp -lpthread
```

I kicked myself when I stumbled on the answer (it's kind of a FAQ for libraries and gcc). For most gcc options order doesn't matter, but for libraries it's critical.

You should not have to specify the library path if the pthread library came with your MinGW distribution (as it seems is the case for you). Also, remember that the command line above will produce an `a.exe` executable; pass `-o test.exe` to avoid that.

Comment: Oh that is sweet. The order change of -lpthread worked. Thank you for your helpful pointers and answers. I love Stackoverflow! The forum that is;  not in my code!